# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sahi.model'

Tags: yolov5

```
import cv2
from sahi.predict import predict
from sahi.model import Yolov5DetectionModel
from sahi.utils.cv import read_image
```

`sahi.predict` and `sahi.utils` works fine but `sahi.model` gives me error:

- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sahi.model'

#### Installed

- pip install torch torchvision torchaudio
- pip install sahi
- pip install yolov5

#### Versions

- Pip version : pip 23.1.2
- Python version : Python 3.11.4

I tried to downgrade sahi to 0.10.8 by using pip install sahi==0.10.8 it didn`t work aswell

Answer (score 0):

There is no module called 'model' in sahi. It's called 'models'. So, to import 'Yolov5DetectionModel' you have to import as below.

```
from sahi.models.yolov5 import Yolov5DetectionModel
```

You don't need to downgrade. You can check all available models here https://github.com/obss/sahi/tree/main/sahi/models